# Angular 2 Http Response .json not performing like expected

Tags: json, angular

I am doing what I have always done when working with data from a server. I am calling and when it returns my data to a subscribe function I don't get a proper object instead I just get the Json String back. Almost like it failed to parse my Json but I used an online parser and it seems just fine.

Code:

```
var status = this.web.post(this.GlobalSettings.ApiSettings.Login_Url + `/${userID}/${password}/${"AppName"}`, JSON.stringify({})).map((result: Response) =>
      {
        var what = result.json() as ServerSource;
        console.log(result.json() as ServerSource);
        return result.json();
      }).share();
```

Alright so every time I have ever worked with JSON data I have always just done result.json in the map function.

I added this as a test and it works but what has changed?

```
var ping = this.web.post(this.GlobalSettings.ApiSettings.Ping_Url, JSON.stringify({})).map((result: Response) =>
      { 
        return JSON.parse(result.json()); //Normally just return result.json();
      });

      ping.subscribe((data: Demo) =>
      { 
        console.log(data);
        console.log(data.Value);
      });
```

The variable what is returned as a string, it logs a string, and anything that subscribes to this post still only receives a string.

Comment: Add the rest of the function please

Comment: There isn't really enough information to go on here. Have you tried [debugging](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/front-end-javascript/debugging-angular-2-applications) the application?

Comment: I have an update I am going to post

Comment: Looking at the difference between the two examples, in the first one you are returning the `share` method, in the other, you are returning the map statement. Could this be why?

Comment: I will have to check but I know that share is important because without it every subscribe will send a new request